# Number representation in Assembler

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-16

```
.data

num DW 7Fh


.CODE


MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX

MOV BX, num
ADD BX, 1
```

I am trying execute this code, but I get this result on emu8086:
The value of BX is 0170h, which is the reason?
[image]

Comment: Can you check what the value at `00000h` is?

Comment: Apparently, `@data` is zero, which is probably not what you want. Add this line at the top of your source file and try again: `.model small`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one of the assembler directory; if you want to use notations like `@data` . Like use `.model tiny` or `.model small` ; according to your need.